# ArrayList is empty after downloading json and setting adapter

Tags: android, json

---

> SOLVED
>
> ---

I'm trying to save img url from json url and I'm kind of stuck here. Please help 
I'm new to android development so sorry if this is a noob question. Thanks!

```
public class images {

private ArrayList<String> url;
private String TAG = "Array list";


public images() {

  url = new ArrayList<>();
    new setupJson().execute("https://wallapp.000webhostapp.com");
}

public ArrayList<String> getImages() {
    return url;
}

public String getOneImage(int position) {
    return url.get(position);
}


public class setupJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        // Http connection
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL urlConn = new URL(strings[0]);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream istream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line+"\n");
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

       // Log.e(TAG,"Result: "+result);


        try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);

    // Getting JSON Array node
    JSONArray imgs = jsonObj.getJSONArray("img");


    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject url_img = imgs.getJSONObject(i);
        String get_url = url_img.getString("url");
        //String get_cat = url_img.getString("category");

        url.add(get_url);

    }

} catch (final JSONException e)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
}
    }
```

After the for loop if I log url variable it shows the value but after
new setupJson().execute();
when I log url it shows empty(i.e [])

---

### UPDATED

Thanks to @Selvin I figured out what was the problem with my code I fixed that moved the setupJson class to mainactivity and onPostExecute I'm setting the adapter.

**MainAcitivity**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    new setupJson().execute();

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String image_url = image.getOneImage(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WallImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("url",image_url);
            startActivity(intent);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),image_url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });



}

public class setupJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String url = "https://wallapp.000webhostapp.com";

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray imgs = jsonObj.getJSONArray("img");


            for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject url_img = imgs.getJSONObject(i);
                String get_url = "https://wallapp.000webhostapp.com/"+url_img.getString("url");
                //String get_cat = url_img.getString("category");
                image.url.add(get_url);
            }




        } catch (final JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this));

    }


}
}
```

Comment: [It is multithreading ...](http://ideone.com/PPHi95) as you see it is `1. : null
3. : null
2. : set` not `1. : null
2. : set
3. : set`   obviously you will not have values right after `new setupJson().execute();` ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check the following help articles: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @Selvin thanks! yeah so I'll check for it after it is completed :D

Comment: @Selvin I m setting the adapter after the thread is compeleted then why in imageAdapter the thumburl is still empty?

Comment: `image = new images();`

Comment: @Selvin where ?